# How to pass a full MySQL query to Datatables?

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I am trying to use datatables.net to build out a table on my website. I have a basic table generating OK using their example and 1 table but I have a complex query with joins, where clause, subquery, etc. and I can't figure out how to create a table with the results.

Their basic example looks like this:

```
// DB table to use
$table = 'TableNameToQuery';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'pk';
```

With this at the end:

```
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
```

The MySQL query looks something along the lines of:

```
select t1.col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1 t1 left join table 2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 where t2.col5 = 'complete'
```

Comment: And what might that query look like?

Comment: Something along the lines of: select t1.col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1 t1 left join table 2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 where t2.col5 = 'complete'

Answer (score 0):

Server-side processing PHP script that is included in DataTables distribution (`examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php`) is very simplistic and doesn't support joins and sub-queries right out of the box.

Emran ul Hadi released modified SSP class that supports what you need, please visit his repository at [github.com/emran/ssp](https://github.com/emran/ssp).

Also in the original SSP class in addition to `SSP::simple` there is a `SSP::complex` method that is defined as follows:

```
static function complex ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult=null, $whereAll=null )
```

where `$whereResult` is WHERE condition to apply to the result set and `$whereAll` is  WHERE condition to apply to all queries. You may use conditions with `SSP::complex` in `$whereResult` and/or `$whereAll` parameters.